# Django/Python3: Convert complex inner join query to

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am developing a book sales application on Django and I need to get a list of the most popular book categories from the books sold.

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField()

class BookCategory(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Sales(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The following SQL is the equivalent of my requirement but I have no idea how to use this using Django models and filtering.

```
sql = "SELECT c.* FROM category c 
    INNER JOIN book_category bc ON c.id = bc.category_id 
    INNER JOIN sales s ON s.book_id = bc.book_id 
    GROUP BY c.id 
    ORDER BY count(s.id) DESC"
```

I have used the following lines of code to execute this but get an error.

```
categories = Category.objects.raw(sql)
```

> Object of type 'RawQuerySet' is not JSON serializable

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the result in pure ORM as,

```
from django.db.models import Count

result = Category.objects.values('name').annotate(sell_count=Count('bookcategory__book__sales'))
```

Comment: This gives all categories with the counts including zeros. I need only the categories of books sold.

Comment: you can filter the result : ```result = Category.objects.values('name').annotate(sell_count=Count('bookcategory__book__sales')).exclude(sell_count=0)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I added this instead .filter(~Q(appointment_count=0))